# Author prominent citation in beamer presentation using biber and biblatex

Tags: beamer, biblatex, biber

I am using references in beamer like this:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},aspectratio=169,10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
```

However, I am only able to cite "in text", like this `\autocite{citation key}` giving "(Author, Year)". This is fine, but sometimes I want: "Autor (Year)" instead.

This would be like `\citet` in natbib.

Any idea how I could achieve this, please?

Comment: Can you please make a compilable minimal working example?

Comment: Have you tried the `natbib=true` option of biblatex?

Comment: This works @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz =)

Comment: Great to hear!!